# No page is displayed for a very basic app in python+jinja2 on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I am new to developing apps on google appengine and to python and jinja. I have been trying this since two days. My first app without jinja worked fine. However this particular app is not displaying anything on the browser. This is the main.py file

```
import webapp2
from webapp2_extra import jinja2
import logging

# this one is to help us parse an RSS feed
import feedparser  
import urllib

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @webapp2.cached_property
    def jinja2(self):
        return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

    def render_response(self, _template, **context):
        # Renders a template and writes the result to the response.
        rv = self.jinja2.render_template(_template, **context)
        self.response.write(rv)

class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        context = {}
        self.render_response('index.html', **context)
#        self.response.write('Byte1')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

And this is the app.yaml file

```
application: ykelkar-byte1
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

I tried to run the sample code that I had and it is getting displayed. So there shouldn't be any installation/configuration issue.

Comment: tried enabling debugging and stepping though line by line?

Comment: use `import jinja2` instead of `from webapp2_extra import jinja2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I noticed is that your import is wrong:

```
from webapp2_extra import jinja2
```

should be:

```
# You have a missing s!
from webapp2_extras import jinja2
```

In general, during development you should enable debugging to catch simple errors like this by setting up your WSGIApplication as follows:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

**EDIT**: Just noticed you already had debugging enabled. An error like this should have been showing you in your development console.

Are you using any particular IDE for development? I have found [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) to be a really good IDE for python development and google app engine specifically (The community edition is free). Maybe you should give it a try to help you out.

Comment: Yes the import statement was wrong. Thank you for the IDE suggestion.